# PoolingOptions and Cassandra - java

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax, apache-flink, datastax-java-driver

I’m using datastax driver to use Cassandra as sink for some data streams with Apache Flink:
I have a problem executing my application raising an error at runtime about the queue which become full after some seconds. I discovered that the default value is 256, that is probably too low for my load, so I have raised it using poolingOptions setting maxRequestsPerConnection as suggested here: http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.1/manual/pooling/.

Unfortunately with the following code I obtain the following error when I launch it:

```
The implementation of the ClusterBuilder is not serializable. 
The object probably contains or references non serializable fields.
```

My code:

```
PoolingOptions poolingOptions = new PoolingOptions();
    poolingOptions
      .setMaxRequestsPerConnection(HostDistance.LOCAL, 32768)
      .setMaxRequestsPerConnection(HostDistance.REMOTE, 10000);


ClusterBuilder cassandraBuilder = new ClusterBuilder() {

    @Override
    public Cluster buildCluster(Cluster.Builder builder) {
        return builder.addContactPoint(CASSANDRA_ADDRESS)
                      .withPort(CASSANDRA_PORT)
                      .withPoolingOptions(poolingOptions)
                      .build();
    }
};

sinkBuilderNormalStream
    .setQuery("INSERT INTO keyspace_local.values_by_sensors_users"
        + " (user, sensor, timestamp, rdf_stream, observed_value, value)"
        + " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);")
    .setClusterBuilder(cassandraBuilder)
    .build();
```

How can I deal with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define the PoolingOptions within ClusterBuilder#buildCluster.